# Local write access issues between notebooks in Databricks

Tags: permissions, databricks

I have multiple notebooks using the same cluster, that periodically need to write a specific file in `/tmp` (let's call it `/tmp/test123_1` in this example). The write should replace the existing file. (Please don't suggest alternatives, this pattern is outside of my control and cannot be changed.)

File creation:

```
f = open("/tmp/test123_1","w")
f.write("hello world")
f.close()
```

When the first notebook creates the file, all is fine. The result of an `ls -l` on the file shows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 spark-34b7428f-46a3-4012-8421-55 spark-34b7428f-46a3-4012-8421-55 11 Nov 17 19:35 /tmp/test123_1
```

Note the user/group, `spark-[uuid]`. I don't know what that's all about, but it appears every time a notebook is connected to a cluster, it runs under a username with that format, but a different uuid each time. Importantly, all these `spark-*` users are members of a `spark-users` group.

If I attach another notebook (which in turn runs under a different `spark-*` user) and try to overwrite that file, it fails:

```
Permission denied: '/tmp/test123_1'
```

Fair enough, the permissions shown earlier don't allow writing to that file by other users.

But as I said, they're all members of `spark-users` group. So from the first notebook, I updated the file to give that group write permissions:

```
import grp
import os
from stat import S_IREAD, S_IWRITE, S_IRGRP, S_IWGRP, S_IROTH

gid = grp.getgrnam("spark-users").gr_gid
os.chown("/tmp/test123_1", -1, gid)
os.chmod("/tmp/test123_1", S_IREAD | S_IWRITE | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH)
```

And `ls` shows:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 spark-34b7428f-46a3-4012-8421-55 spark-users 11 Nov 17 19:35 /tmp/test123_1
```

And just to confirm the user from the second notebook is in the same group, output of `id`:

```
uid=1009(spark-7f73065c-850f-473d-a863-e1) gid=1010(spark-7f73065c-850f-473d-a863-e1) groups=1010(spark-7f73065c-850f-473d-a863-e1),1002(spark-users)
```

But writing to the file from that notebook still fails with the same error. Reading works fine, same as it did before I changed the permissions. If I remove the read permission, reading fails, so I know the permission is having an effect, but I don't understand why it's not allowing write when the permissions seem to be correct. It has write access to the `/tmp` directory, same as the user from the first notebook.

Any troubleshooting hints or explanation of this behaviour appreciated.

Comment: it looks like you're using shared cluster - it's expected behavior there because we need to isolate users

Comment: So even if I've changed the permissions of a file to grant other users access, Databricks will somehow prevent that access?